# US Extended overlay or decals

Tags: keyboard, accessories

I typically use the US Extended keyboard for typing, however, I can't always recall where certain deadkeys are. Does anyone make an overlay, or keyboard stickers which can be used to make my keyboard more accessible for international diacritics?

Alternatively, is there any software around for making these decals?

Note: [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/120956/79316) shows what a US Extended layout looks like for those who are unaware.

Comment: What is a deadkey? not functioning or not used?

Comment: @Buscar웃, it's a key used to type an accent, for example option-e is "´" then I type the letter e to get "é".

Comment: in this case if you hold the "e" key for few seconds is there a pop up showing you the options for the "e" key ?

Comment: e é è ê ë ė as example

Comment: @Buscar웃, no, however using the option [deadkey] letter method is a slightly older (and better in my opinion) concept. Using deadkeys also allows for a greater number of accents being used on a character.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/wheres-the-us-international-keyboard-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks for the layout.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that method, I use the handy pop up when holding a letter that requires accent. I also modified that popup application to accents I use more frequently and that were not a part of the pop up. Since in all cases the alphabet is still Latin the only difference is the accent for all languages. Example the "sch" is a Š in Eastern Eu. So all I have to do when typing in Ester Eu is to hold the "S" and pick the one I want from the popup, nothing to remember.

Comment: As I like to touch type, I don't look at the keyboard.  Much easier for me to hold a letter for a second then type the corresponding number. Violà! That said, to each his own.