# US Extended Input Source missing

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm wanting to type some Pinyin characters (e.g. adding a `bar` above an `a` with `Alt A + A`) and am following this guide http://pinpinchinese.com/blog/how-to-type-pinyin-tone-marks-mac-os-x-yosemite/

However, I don't see the option of a US Extended Input source. Here's what I do see:

[image: English Input Sources on Mac]

Any suggestions?

Fwiw, I'm running El Capitan 10.11.2 (15C50).

Comment: [Try ABC extended: it's been renamed in later versions of OS X from, US Extended. No idea why this decision was made.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/wheres-the-us-international-keyboard-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

Comment: @JMY1000  I strongly suspect the name change was done to "de-nationalize" this layout, which can be used for any latin script anywhere. They also added ABC, which is just a denationalized "US".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In El Capitan the US Extended keyboard was renamed to ABC Extended.