# Some native keyboard accent shortcuts not working since OS X 10.11.3 Update

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, internationalization

I have a Qwerty keyboard on my MacBook Pro late-2015, set to the standard US layout, that I sometime use to write French accentuated characters.

However, since the last OS X update, some accent shortcuts are not working anymore. More specifically, <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> (+ some vowel), which used to produce circumflex accents now writes `§`, and <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, used for c cedilla, is now used for capitalising the last written word. I can still write these characters using the press and hold method, but it's pretty inefficient.

How can I re-enable these accent shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard US keyboard layout always yields a <kbd>§</kbd> if <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> is pressed.

To get your desired results enable the US extended (or ABC Extended in OS X 10.11) keyboard layout:

- <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> -> <kbd>ˆ</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> -> <kbd>ê</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> -> <kbd>ç</kbd>

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. Apparently, [the US extended keyboard does not exist anymore on OS X El Capitan, and ABC Extended has to be used instead.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/wheres-the-us-international-keyboard-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks)

Comment: @PierreThalamy They just changed the name of US Extended to ABC Extended, presumably to "denationalize" it, since it is appropriate for use with any latin script in any country.  And those who want to use the US layout without the US Flag showing can now select "ABC" instead.

Answer (score 3):

Go to system preferences/keyboard/input sources and make sure that only the item called "US International PC" is on the list, or the item called "ABC Extended" (known as "US Extended" prior to OS X 10.11).

(The standard US layout does not use Option 6 for circumflex, it uses Option i. The US International PC layout uses Shift 6, while ABC Extended uses Option 6. I suspect you were using one of these layouts rather than "US".)

Answer (score 0):

I realise that you probablyuse the command shortcuts for increased speed, but it may be helpful to you (and others) to consider the slightly longer method of holding down a character until the "pop up" choice list appears.  For example, holding down <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>e</kbd> on my (British English) system yields:

[image]
[image]

This has the added benefit that the list can be customised to a certain extent (if you are [happy messing with the plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/49659/9495) files)

Comment: Did you miss the part of his question where he says " I can still write these characters using the press and hold method, but it's pretty inefficient."?