# How to use Windows US-Intl keyboard layout on a Mac?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, etc. all have a keyboard layout called US International, which turns the right Alt key into a modifer that lets you type common symbols from European languages, as well as adding various dead keys.

Is there any way to use this keyboard layout on a Mac? Macs do have a layout called "U.S. International - PC", but despite the name, it doesn't match the keyboard layout used on other OSes. It makes " and ' combine with certain letters but otherwise doesn't appear to change anything at all and in particular, holding the right Alt key doesn't work.

I don't want to have to memorize a whole different keyboard layout just for Macs, or hold each key and wait for a popup or whatever.

The Alt level of Windows US International, which I am used to looks like this:

[image]

But the same level on Apple's US International PC is a lot different and looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The answer to your question, along with pictures of the answer, look like they are found in a previously posted question. You can find what you are looking for [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/wheres-the-us-international-keyboard-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks).

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate.  He wants Apple's US International PC layout to behave like the Windows version.  It has nothing to do with the layout called US Extended answered earlier.

Comment: @TomGewecke Do you see a way to edit the question to make this more clear? If yes, please do so.

Comment: @patrix Gave it a try via some images.

Comment: Keep in mind that this does not influence the method of holding down a letter (like the a,e,n,i,o,u etc.) which then pops up a balloon with the optional additions to that letter. Pressing and holding n shows ñ and ń for example.

Comment: @JohnKeates Antimony says in his question "I don't want to have to ...hold each key and wait for a popup

Answer (score 3):

You can make the Alt/Option level of Apple's US International PC behave like the version you are used to by creating a custom keyboard layout with the app [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

For reference the Alt/Option behavior of Windows US International is [here](https://www.csbsju.edu/Documents/MCL/resource/use-int-keyboard.pdf).

Note that on a Mac both left and right alt/option keys normally do the same thing, i.e. create special characters.

PS  If in fact your right alt key does not produce any characters at all, then something is broken with your keyboard or software.

An experimental keyboard that tries to conform to the Windows version can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpi1kat7gmeifj3/Win%20US%20Intl.keylayout?dl=0).

Note:  If you want something like one of the Linux versions of "US International" which have a dozen or more dead keys for making a huge number of diacritic and other characters, then the Apple equivalent is ABC Extended, whose layout is however quite different.  For that see this [earlier question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120938/wheres-the-us-international-keyboard-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks).

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll find on macOS is the `English - Irish` layout for `áéíóú`, you don't need to type `alt+e+a` for á, just `alt+a`. If you want to match US_intl character by character, you'll need to create your own `.keylayout` with [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) and drop it under `/Library/Keyboard Layouts`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a layout created by community members, for example

- [U.S. International wo dead keys](https://www.twam.info/hardware/us-international-on-os-x) by Tobias Müller, or
- [Us no dead key](https://github.com/WillerWasTaken/mac-us-int-no-dead-key) by WillerWasTaken.

You may have to compare and try them out to find the exact variant you desire, or maybe tweak a detail or two using [Ukelele](https://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) yourself.